# InvokeRequired not returning value from method

Tags: vb.net

I use InvokeRequired for thread safety but when it comes to my method and if i pass value as true it always showing me false. Why and how to fix it?

```
Public Sub InitGrid(Optional myValue As Boolean = False)
            If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf InitGrid))
            Else
MsgBox(myValue.ToString()) //always false...
            End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Action(of T) version:

```
Public Sub InitGrid(Optional myValue As Boolean = False)
  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Boolean)(AddressOf InitGrid), myValue)
  Else
    MessageBox.Show(myValue.ToString())
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is fine, but why define a new delegate, when you can use `Action(Of Boolean)`? Like this `Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Boolean)(AddressOf InitGrid), myValue)`

Comment: @Verdolino Yeah, I'll post it that way.